# Pass a valid endpoint name to the service client constructor

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to use web service for weather

```
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
```

I make console application and try to use this service. First of all I add reference and name the reference `WeatherService` and write below code

```
Console.WriteLine("Now we get weather, please wait .......");

            WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoapClient w = new WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoapClient();
            Console.WriteLine(w.GetWeather("Lahore","Pakistan"));
```

But it gives me a exception

```
Additional information: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
```

I am learning web services and don't know why this happens. Any one help me on this is great favor. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your app.config, find needed  then pass it's name to GlobalWeatherSoapClient(here):
in your app.config should be setting like this:

```
      <endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GlobalWeatherSoap"
    contract="WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoap" name="GlobalWeatherSoap" />
```

get name and pass it to client:

```
WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoapClient w = new WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoapClient("GlobalWeatherSoap");
```

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, although there is not data but exception is resolved. Do you have any link for web service that return some data?

Comment: I'm not this service developer so I can't answer you. In wsdl you provided there is just one address - "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx" (you can see it in the end). But I think it's simply does not have the info you need or in knows Lahore by another name. This service also has action GetCitiesByCountry - maybe you should check it to ensure Lahore is in list

Comment: Its interface. When I try to use it like WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoap ws2; string cities = ws2.GetCitiesByCountry("Pakistan"); it give me error "Use of unassigned local variable ws2" any idea to resolve this issue?